# Lightweight library to create XML strings from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, node.js

Need to generate OpenOffice XML strings on node.js and browser environments including Chrome and IE 10/11.

It seems like writing XML would be a solved problem and a library would exist.  Many people upvoted @Jason's advice to use a library not invent ones own.

On Node.js  `cheerio.js` is great.  Ok, so you have to add a couple arguments to create a node, as in `var $el = cheerio(<'patternFill/>',null,null,{xmlMode:true})` but that's okay.

On the browser, you'd thing jQuery would have this.  But I'm going crazy:

- `$('<patternFill')` lower cases tag names on creation, so you have to use $el = jQuery.parseXML('') to keep the camel case as XML is case sensitive.
- jQuery `$el.html()` lower cases tagnames and includes only the inner HTML, so you have to use $el[0].outerHTML with `XMLSerializer` instead
- jQuery `outerHTML` isn't defined in IE 10 or IE11 ([How to reliably convert XML to String in IE 10/11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799419/how-to-reliably-convert-xml-to-string-in-ie-10-11))

So fine. Writing an XML string seems simple enough.

But then I have to escape quotes and such which brought me to this post, in which [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Then it turns out there are different kinds of quotes.  What about embedded escaped quotes, such as `"\""` -- do I turn that into `"\&quot;"` or `"&quot;"`?  Etc.

So now it feels like I'm reinventing jQuery and cheerio.  This can't be right.  Is there a simple Javascript library for writing XML programmatically?

Comment: Have you looked at [marknote](https://code.google.com/p/marknote/wiki/DevelopersGuide)? or [JKL](http://www.kawa.net/works/js/jkl/parsexml-e.html)?

Comment: Another trick I like to use with jQuery is to make the xml a jQuery object. A Quick for instance: if you ajax in an XML sheet, then in your success callback you can do `success: function(data){ var $xml = $(data) }` which would then allow you to make calls like `$xml.find('node')`. It's pretty quick and handy.